# check to see if user input is percentage or dollar

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript. Building a custom javascript calculator to set pricing for some products. There is sometimes a fee that is added. This fee is either a percentage of cost or an actual dollar amount. If it is a percentage, it will have a percentage sign. After researching, came up with the following solution that works only if a dollar amount is entered but not if percentage is entered. Is there a better solution?

```
<form name="calculator">
<input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" onkeyup="calculate()">
<input type="text" name="fee" placeholder="fee" onkeyup="calculate()">
<br>
<p>The answer is: </p>
<p id="testAnswer"></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function calculate(){
var a = Number(document.calculator.cost.value);
var b = Number(document.calculator.fee.value);

if(b==""){
    var result1= a;
} else {
    if (/^\d+(\.\d+)?%$/.test(b)) {
        result1 =(1+b)*a;
    } else {
        var result1 = b+a;
    }
}
document.getElementById("testAnswer").innerHTML = result1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It might be a better practice to have two different inputs, one for amount, one for percent. You could have a radio button that would switch between them. That way you never have to rely on a user putting in the proper symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are converting the input to a number with:

```
var a = Number(document.calculator.cost.value);
var b = Number(document.calculator.fee.value);
```

Any symbols will cause that conversion to fail and therefore you wouldn't be able to perform your test.

```js
var num = Number("234.50%");
console.log(num); // Not a Number
```

Instead, before doing the conversion, just simply test for the presence of the symbol with `.indexOf` which returns `-1` when the test can't find a match.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("num1");

a.addEventListener("input", function(){

  console.clear();

  // Always trim leading or trailing spaces from user input
  var input = a.value.trim();
  
  var unit = null;
  
  if(input.indexOf("%") > -1){
    unit = "Percent";
  } else if(input.indexOf("$") > -1) {
    unit = "Dollar";
  }
  
  console.log(unit);  // null until % or $ is entered
  
  // Now that you know what the unit is,
  // you can convert to a number. Use parseInt() 
  // or parseFloat() for this
  var inputNum = parseInt(input, 10);
  console.log(typeof inputNum, inputNum);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
```

Having said all of that, I agree with the comments that a better way to handle this is by not asking the user to input the unit at all and just provide radio buttons:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("num1");

// Set up click event for radio buttons that enables number input
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='unit']")).forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    a.removeAttribute("disabled");
  });
});

a.addEventListener("input", function(){

  console.clear();

  // Always trim leading or trailing spaces from user input
  var input = a.value.trim();
  
  // Just get the value of the selected radio button
  var unit = document.querySelector("input[name='unit']:checked").value;
  
  console.log(unit);  // null until % or $ is entered
  
  // Now that you know what the unit is,
  // you can convert to a number. Use parseInt() 
  // or parseFloat() for this
  var inputNum = parseInt(input, 10);
  console.log(typeof inputNum, inputNum);
});
```

```html
<!-- If you expect only digits, you can use a number type -->
<input type="radio" name="unit" value="%">%
<input type="radio" name="unit" value="$">$
<input type="number" id="num1" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you @ScottM. Very useful information. I am trying to match an Excel sheet that a company is very familiar with. In Excel you can enter either a % or a number in a cell with no problem. If I'm able to do so with my limited experience, I will be exporting the results to a database and then back to the Excel file for printing in the format they are used to.